# Overlapping IP's in C#

Tags: c#, ip, overlap, subnet

Ok im writing a program in C# and im trying to detect overlappin IP pools or overlapping subnet wildcards if you will. Ive used the NOT logic to turn it from a wildcard to a subnet. Now I have to detect whether an IP is overlapping or not.
An example:

192.168.1.1 255.255.0.0

overlaps

192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

So I want my code to be able to detect this. Does anyone know anything about this.

Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, i tried to convert subnet address and broadcast address to integer and compare it but it says me that 10.0.0.0 255.192.0.0 overlaps 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0... So I am little bit desperate right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert both the IP and the subnet mask from the dotted-decimal notation into a 32bit integers. Lets call them `ip1_addr`, `ip2_addr`, `ip1_msk`, `ip2_msk`.

First compare the two masks and find which one is smaller (smaller the mask value, larger the scope), you will use that one for the second step. Then do a bitwise AND of each ip address and the subnet mask and check if the result is the same `ip1_addr & mask == ip2_addr & mask`.